# python: Parsing error when converting to tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I'm currently trying to convert an object detection model to a tflite model. I've used the https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/index tutorial and achieved to convert a few different models to tflite, but my problem has arrived with a not-so-developed model: faced (https://github.com/iitzco/faced). I've used the same code tensorflow suggests, but I've encountered some errors when converting the model.

Used code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Convert the model
saved_model_dir = '/directory_previous_to_saved_model.pb'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('/directory/faced.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

The error that shows is shown below:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc:577] String field 'tensorflow.MetaGraphDef.MetaInfoDef.meta_graph_version' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 100, in parse_saved_model
    saved_model.ParseFromString(file_content)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/bin/tflite_convert", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 697, in main
    app.run(main=run_main, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 312, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 258, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 680, in run_main
    _convert_tf2_model(tflite_flags)
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/tflite_convert.py", line 251, in _convert_tf2_model
    converter = lite.TFLiteConverterV2.from_saved_model(
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1270, in from_saved_model
    saved_model = _load(saved_model_dir, tags)
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 869, in load
    return load_internal(export_dir, tags, options)["root"]
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py", line 881, in load_internal
    loader_impl.parse_saved_model_with_debug_info(export_dir))
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 56, in parse_saved_model_with_debug_info
    saved_model = _parse_saved_model(export_dir)
  File "/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/loader_impl.py", line 103, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError("Cannot parse file %s: %s." % (path_to_pb, str(e)))
OSError: Cannot parse file b'/directory_previous_to_saved_model.pb/saved_model.pb': Error parsing message.
```

I've searched on the web, but haven't be able to find any solutions.

I've also tried to do as it says and send bytes instead of Strings, but I couldn't do it, because i don't know how to specify the 'bytes' type.

Comment: could`'/directory_previous_to_saved_model.pb'` actually be`'/directory_previous_to_saved_model/'` ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, the code is able to get the correct path either way

Comment: the code gives an error with the wrong path though

Comment: I know, but just to be sure, i changed it as you said and the program displayed the same error

Comment: `directory_previous_to_saved_model.pb` looks like a file, not a directory. is that on purpose?

Comment: Does this file `directory_previous_to_saved_model.pb/saved_model.pb` exist?

Comment: Yes, it was just my way to specify the directory, but lets just say its "/directory_previous_to_saved_model/"

Comment: Yes, it does exist @ExtraFishness

Comment: does [this](https://github.com/microsoft/MMdnn/issues/587#issuecomment-465394740) help?

Comment: **tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()** already prepares the saved model to be converted. The actual problem is the parsing the command does which can't be done with strings

Comment: Did you save the model using `tf.saved_model.save(model, path_to_dir)`. To load the saved model it is recommended to save the model using `tf.saved_model.save()`.  The function `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model` is recommended for savedmodel format. Thanks

Comment: @TFer the problem is that faced gives you 2 saved models but uses them in a weird way. The model is already saved, but I feel incapable of customizing it as there is very little information about it in the Internet

Answer (score 0):

To convert your model to tflite format you have to save your model in tensorflow save format using tf.keras.models.save_model()

Then you can convert that save model to tflite using

```
# Convert the model
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir) # path to the SavedModel directory
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the model.
with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

For more details please refer to this [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/tensorflow/+/632ff3f6169ef18a6947c53bd6f3cb5bf7fc26a6/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/convert/index.md). Thank You.